# increment or decrement without using laravel methods mangodb jassengers

Tags: laravel, laravel-mongodb

I want to update documents and decrement specific column value. it is possible to use    `Model::where('','')->update(['count' => \DB::raw('count- 1')]);` i'm using **jenssegers/laravel-mongodb** package.

I want decrement and update documents values together.

```
$result= Source::where('')
         ->where('');
$result->decrement('count');
$result->update([
   'column' => true,
]);
```

This code decrement count value but can not update column values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it from laravel [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#increment-and-decrement)
updated column value pass 3rd parameter as array in decrement method

```
Model::where('', null)
        ->where('', '')
        ->decrement('count', 1, [
            'column1' => value1,
            'column2' => value2,
            'column3' => value3,
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB):

Perform increments or decrements (default 1) on specified attributes:

```
Cat::where('name', 'Kitty')->increment('age');

Car::where('name', 'Toyota')->decrement('weight', 50);
```

Comment: what about Cat other fields update as well

Comment: @AliRaza yes it can, read through docs (link already in my answer). And dont forget to approve my answer if you found it good :)